# Can a command binding act on a targeted UIElement attribute other than IsEnabled?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I like how binding a button's Command attribute to a ICommand object handles both the Click event and the enabled/disabled status. Is there any way, using my own commands / CommandBinding class / MarkerExtension / attached custom DependencyProperty / (whatever else), that command binding also affects other target attributes?

Say for example I use my own derived command, which has a Visible boolean property. Upon binding the button's Command attribute, I would like my command object's Visible property to act on the button's visibility, just like the CanExecute method acts on the IsEnabled property (no need to bind the button's IsEnabled property).

Is there a way to achieve something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can. A customized command with custom logic and with a bit of knowledge about wpf hacking may be placed on a Button and can be used for other things than just switching between enabled and disabled state.

At the same time, no it cannot. Commands are used on user input hence why it makes sence to have a command fire on Button.Clicked, but it doesnt make much sence in wpf world to attach a command just for changing Visibility. If you wish to change Visibility, wpf offers you simple Binding instead of Commands. Changing visibility is not really a user input anyways. Use Commands only on user input for everything else use Bindings.

Futhermore read the post from X.j, it explains you how you could use Binding properly on Button.Visibility property.

Comment: Is there any example of such a hack you can refer me to? I couldn't seem to find any.

Comment: Nobody really hacks this. Thats why you cant find it on the web. I suggest you to not to hack and take a look at X.J. answer. Your question was can a command binding act on a targeted UIElement attribute other than IsEnabled? I tell you yes it can but its not wpf usual bread. Though here is how. Attach a dependency property of type ICommandSource to a Control you wish to hack.

Comment: You can try it out. Attach a property of type ICommand or ICommandSource. When you inside attached property changed event you can add custom logic to the control you attached the property to.

Comment: I see your point, this actually was my first idea, before even asking. I just hoped there would be a better solution than having this second Command property. Appearantly there isn't.

Comment: Well you could create a new class that derives from Button and stuff everything together in one command.

Comment: I mentionned Button in my question to keep it as clear and concise as possible, but the truth is what I'd really like to do is acting over how a command gets binded to a UIElement implementing ICommandSource in a global way. That means of course Button, HyperLink, MenuItem and perhaps 3rd party controls as well. If there's no way to do that then I'll either go for an attached dependency property, or just bind the attribute, despite how much I hate it. :)

Comment: Sorry, english isn't my main language. :) What I mean is that I wanted to act on every possible UIElement that implements ICommandSource.

Comment: Care to be a bit more specific? :) What would be wrapped? And how would that wrapper be used?

Comment: You would end up having something like this in XAML: <CommandExtender Command={Binding AnotherCommand}><CommandExtender.Element><Button Command={Binding SomeCommand}/></CommandExtender.Element></CommandExtender> As you can see you create a custom FrameworkElement in my case I called it CommandExtender that can be used in xaml and it stores an UIElement inside. When Button.Visibility changed you execute AnotherCommand. When Button.Clicked buttons own Command gets fired. Basically you wrap a ANY UIElement and extend it with an another command. :) I suggest you to post a new question about this.

Comment: That's pretty cool, but since the initial target was to reduce the necessary amount of XAML code and make it look prettier, I don't think that surrounding each concerned control with an extender will do the job. Still, I really must thank you for your great ideas, it helps my overall comprehension of XAML and WPF.

Answer (score 1):

For other dependency property (like Visibility) on the button, you should bind it to a property in your ViewModel class (since you tagged MVVM), which should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interfac. And you can then manipulate the property on the ViewModel class to affect the button visibility. Is there something which can't be solved by normal binding here?

Comment: I know I can bind the Visibility property to whatever I want. I'd just find it more convenient being able to control both IsEnabled and Visibility properties upon binding a special type of command. Having to bind two properties over and over for the same desired behavior is counter-productive and error-prone; two things I of course want to avoid as much as I can.